# Java: Replace String (with brackets!)

Tags: java, string, excel

I'm currently working on a small program that:

- Reads an Excel document (.xlsx, using SmartXLS) and saves the content in a long String (a new line for each cell)
- Reads a config file and then converts substrings in the long String (replaceAll) and/or adds a prefix, according to the examples in the config file
- Outputs the final String into a txt file

Example for the conversion: a b c (with a tab in between each of the parts), e.g. "its[ ]bracket" -> "itsabracket" with

```
tagname [ ] a
```

in the config file ("[ ]" gets replaced with "a"). a is the tag that tells me, what columns get converted, b is the original substring and c is the String b has to be converted into.

The problem is: I already know that brackets (round, curly and square) are going to be used in the config file but I don't know, if it's going to be just a single one or maybe even longer phrases (with letters, digits,..) in between the brackets.

```
String s = s.replaceAll(convert[i].original, convert[i].new);
```

for "[ ]" -> "a" writes [a] into the output file and if I do the following first, when it's reading the config file and saves everything in the "convert" array, it throws a PatternSyntaxException ("Unclosed character class near index 0"):

```
if(ss.contains("[")) {
    ss = ss.replaceAll("[", "\\[");
} else if(ss.contains("]")) {
    ss = s.replaceAll("]", "\\]");
}
```

With

```
if(ss.contains("\\[")) {
    ss = ss.replaceAll("\\[", "\\\\[");
} else if(ss.contains("\\]")) {
    ss = s.replaceAll("\\]", "\\\\]");
}
```

it outputs "[a]" again.

Any ideas, how I can make this work?

Comment: To match `[` in a regex you have to write `\\\\[` Note, you could have both an `[` and an `]` in a string.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you sure?

Comment: Your conversions - are they supposed to be regular expression patters or just literal strings? If the latter, why not use the `String.replace` method rather than `String.replaceAll`?

Comment: @Pshemo you are right `\\[` is fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I already tried using "String s = s.replaceAll("[\\[.\\]]", conv[i].new);" but that replaces all "[" or "]" with the new String, so it changes e.g. "its[ ]bracket" into "itsa abracket" instead of "itsabracket". Furthermore, I can't be sure if there'll always be two and not just a single one or even three or more brackets.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There won't be patterns or huge amounts of repetitions but it's possible that it has to replace more than one (there won't be different ones in a string, though) in a single String -> I need replaceAll.

Comment: @Neph what should be the output for "its[ ]]bracket" is it   "itsabracket"?

Comment: Well, @Neph, read the documentation for [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). It replaces more than once in a single string.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap No, if I use the conversion "[ ] a" (with a tab between the "[ ]" and the "a", so I can use split() with \t), then it should output "itsa]bracket".

Comment: @RealSkeptic "s = s.replace("[\\[.\\]]", conv[i].new);" doesn't replace anything, neither does the same thing but without the dot.

Comment: What is the content of `s`? And I was asking you whether your conversions are patterns or literal strings.

Comment: @Neph difference between `replaceAll` and `replace` is that `replaceAll` uses regex syntax, but `replace` doesn't. That is all. Both methods will replace all occurrences of searched text (naming of methods should be better like `replaceRegex` instead of `replaceAll`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) It accepts character sequence unlike replaceAll.You dont have to use escape characters for [] etc.

```
 String s = s.replace(convert[i].original, convert[i].new);
```

**input**
its[][]]bracket
tagname [ ] a

**output**

itsaa]bracket

Hope this is what you want to achieve using your code.